# How to parse Chinese character in android using xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I have questions about the android developing
when I want to parse the xml files with some chinese character using the xmlpullparser but the result show some question mark symbols. I have no idea about it. I have found some results in the google, which is solved by add the utf-8 string. However, it seems not work for my program, can anyone help me??:(

```
protected ArrayList<ExerciseList> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ArrayList<ExerciseList> exercises =null;
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL("http://.../viewexercise_test.xml");
                    ExerciseList_parser exerciselist_parser = new ExerciseList_parser();
                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");

                    exerciselist_parser.parse(is);
                    exercises = exerciselist_parser.getExercise();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print(e);
                }

        return exercises;

     }
```

The following is the parser code

```
public void parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in, "utf-8");
            parser.nextTag();
            readFeed(parser);

        } finally {
            in.close();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using Pull Parser but I think you got it wrong on calling utf

Well this is my code using DOM but the logic is still there

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
... // probably some other code to check for HTTP response status code
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
String xml = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Are you sure that it is **utf-8** and have you tried  URLDecoder.decode